# Error secuencia if python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

tengo este codigo, el cual me genera el error que el programa entra en varios if sin razon,es en la zona del 50% de descuento(comentado en el programa) cuando en el mismo if le aclaro que se verifiquen ciertas caracteristicas para que ingrese al mismo, sin embargo por ejemplo quiero que ingrese en el primer if, colocando en consola los valores correctos y que cumplen con lo pedido, el programa funciona pero por alguna razon no imprime solo el resultado, si no tambien otros if que no tienen ni sentido, o se saltan la verificacion o es algo que no veo o comprendo, alguien que me explique, gracias.

```
        print("Seleccione la prenda de su agrado: ")
    print("remeras $150, ", "camisas $300, ", "pantalones $400, ", "faldas $ 200, ", "vestidos $300, ", "abrigos $500, ", "calzado $400.")
    print("\n")
    print("Super Puntos:\n"
      "remeras 100P, ", "camisas 200P, ", "pantalones 250P, ", "faldas 150P, ", "vestidos 200P, ", "abrigos 450P, ","calzado 250P" )
    print("\n")

    #Asignacion de prendas y precios.
    prenda1 = input(str("Ingrese la prenda n° 1: "))
    precio1= float(input("Ingrese el precio de la prenda: " + "$"))

    prenda2 = input(str("Ingrese la prenda n° 2: "))
    precio2= float(input("Ingrese el precio de la prenda: " + "$"))

    prenda3 = input(str("Ingrese la prenda n° 3: "))
    precio3= float(input("Ingrese el precio de la prenda: " + "$"))

    prenda_precio1 = (prenda1) + " $" + str(precio1)
    prenda_precio2 = (prenda2) + " $" + str(precio2)
    prenda_precio3 = (prenda3) + " $" + str(precio2)

    precio_total = float(precio1 + precio2 + precio3)
    print("Total sin promo: " + "$" + str(precio_total))

    #Tipo de pago.
    pago_unico = input("Ingrese la forma de pago: ")

    #Pago contado
    if (pago_unico == "contado") or (pago_unico == "Contado"):
      total_descuento = precio_total - ((precio_total * 10) / 100)
      print("Total descuento: " + "$" + str(total_descuento))
      ahorro_total = ((precio_total * 10) / 100)
      print("Ahorro total: " + "$" + str(ahorro_total))
 #Descuento del 50%   
    if ((prenda1 == prenda2) != prenda3) and (precio1 > precio2):
        mitad_precio1_1 = prenda1 + " $" + str(precio1)
        descuento_mitad1_1 = prenda1 + " $" + str((precio1 * 50) / 100)
        print("Por llevar dos prendas iguales tiene un 50% de descuento en la de mayor valor!!")
        print("Se aplica un 50% a la prenda de mayor valor: " + str(mitad_precio1_1))
        print("Descuento 50a11: " + str(descuento_mitad1_1))
    else:
        print(" ")

    if ((prenda1 == prenda3) != prenda2) and (prenda1 > prenda3):
        mitad_precio1_2 = prenda1 + " $" + str(precio1)
        descuento_mitad1_2 = prenda1 + " $" + str((precio1 * 50) / 100)
        print("Por llevar dos prendas iguales tiene un 50% de descuento en la de mayor valor!!")
        print("Se aplica un 50% a la prenda de mayor valor: " + str(mitad_precio1_2))
        print("Descuento 50a12: " + str(descuento_mitad1_2))
    else:
        print(" ")

    if ((prenda2 == prenda1) != prenda3) and (precio2 > precio1):
        mitad_precio2_1 = prenda2 + " $" + str(precio2)
        descuento_mitad2_1 = prenda2 + " $" + str((precio2 * 50) /100)
        print("Por llevar dos prendas iguales tiene un 50% de descuento en la de mayor valor!!")
        print("Se aplica un 50% a la prenda de mayor valor: " + str(mitad_precio2_1))
        print("Descuento 50b11: " + str(descuento_mitad2_1))
    else:
        print(" ")

    if ((prenda2 == prenda3) != prenda1) and (precio2 > precio3):
        mitad_precio2_2 = prenda2 + " $" + str(precio2)
        descuento_mitad2_2 = prenda2 + " $" + str((precio2 * 50) /100)
        print("Por llevar dos prendas iguales tiene un 50% de descuento en la de mayor valor!!")
        print("Se aplica un 50% a la prenda de mayor valor: " + str(mitad_precio2_2))
        print("Descuento 50b12: " + str(descuento_mitad2_2))
    else:
        print(" ")

    if ((prenda3 == prenda1) != prenda2) and (precio3 > precio1):
        mitad_precio3_1 = prenda3 + " $" + str(precio3)
        descuento_mitad3_1 = prenda3 + " $" + str((precio3 * 50) / 100)
        print("Por llevar dos prendas iguales tiene un 50% de descuento en la de mayor valor!!")
        print("Se aplica un 50% a la prenda de mayor valor:" + str(mitad_precio3_1))
        print("Descuento 50c11: " + str(descuento_mitad3_1))
    else:
        print("")

    if ((prenda3 == prenda2) != prenda1) and (precio3 > precio2):
        mitad_precio3_2 = prenda3 + " $" + str(precio3)
        descuento_mitad3_2 = prenda3 + " $" + str((precio3 * 50) / 100)
        print("Por llevar dos prendas iguales tiene un 50% de descuento en la de mayor valor!!")
        print("Se aplica un 50% a la prenda de mayor valor:" + str(mitad_precio3_2))
        print("Descuento 50c12: " + str(descuento_mitad3_2))
    else:
        print("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agusavendaño por fin finalize de limpiar tu código, creo que este es el resultado final que querías:

```
total = 0.0;
def compararPrendas(prenda1, prenda2, precio1, precio2):
   mitad_precio = prenda1 + " $" + str(precio1 / 2)
   precio_total = str(prenda1 + " $" + str((precio1 * 50) /100))
   print("¡Por llevar dos prendas iguales tiene un 50% de descuento en la de mayor valor!")
   print("Se aplica un 50% a la prenda de mayor valor: " + str(mitad_precio))
   print("Descuento 50%: $" + precio_total)
   print("Precio total: $" + str(total - precio_total))

print("Seleccione la prenda de su agrado: ")
print("remeras $150, camisas $300, pantalones $400, faldas $ 200, vestidos $300, abrigos $500, calzado $400.")
print(" ")
print("Super Puntos:") 
print("remeras 100P, camisas 200P, pantalones 250P, faldas 150P, vestidos 200P, abrigos 450P, calzado 250P" )
print(" ")
#Asignacion de prendas y precios.
prenda1 = str(input("Ingrese la prenda n° 1: ")).strip()
precio1= float(input("Ingrese el precio de la prenda: " + "$"))
prenda2 = str(input("Ingrese la prenda n° 2: ")).strip()
precio2= float(input("Ingrese el precio de la prenda: " + "$"))
prenda3 = str(input("Ingrese la prenda n° 3: ")).strip()
precio3= float(input("Ingrese el precio de la prenda: " + "$"))

prenda_precio1 = (prenda1) + " $" + str(precio1)
prenda_precio2 = (prenda2) + " $" + str(precio2)
prenda_precio3 = (prenda3) + " $" + str(precio2)

precio_total = float(precio1 + precio2 + precio3)
total = precio_total
print("Total sin promo: " + "$" + str(precio_total))

#Tipo de pago.
pago_unico = str(input("Ingrese la forma de pago: "))

#Pago contado
if (pago_unico.lower() == "contado"):
   total_descuento = precio_total - ((precio_total * 10) / 100)
   print("Total descuento: " + "$" + str(total_descuento))
   ahorro_total = ((precio_total * 0) / 100)
   print("Ahorro total: " + "$" + str(ahorro_total))
 #Descuento del 50%
   if (prenda1 == prenda2):
      compararPrendas(prenda1, prenda2, precio1, precio2)
   else:
       print("prenda1 != prenda2")
   if (prenda1 == prenda3):
      compararPrendas(prenda1, prenda3, precio1, precio3)
   else:
       print("prenda1 != prenda3")
   if (prenda2 == prenda3):
      compararPrendas(prenda1, prenda3, precio1, precio3)
   else:
       print("prenda2 != prenda3")
```